# Website/webpage template which uses Modernizr?

Tags: templates, html, css, themes, modernizr

I am looking for a website or web page template which uses Modernizr effectively. I looked at a couple from ThemeForest but I couldn't see where Modernizr came into play. In fact I disable loading the Modernizr js file and the web page worked the same way.

Looking for a template which has classes for feature & no-feature. Where 'feature' is a html5 or css3 feature.

Comment: Why is Modernizr a requirement? Are you hoping to achieve a specific goal?

Comment: Modernizr helps a html5 site work in non html5 browsers

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awesome Html5 template that has Modernizr built-in: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: It's not a website template.  I am looking for a template with layout, text, images.. content.. etc.